# Emacs region highlighting

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a way to highlight a string in a text (but not ALL such strings) in a buffer where  font-lock-mode is on.

Let's imagine I have a buffer with SQL mode and I want to highlight a string in it. 
The following code does not work

```
(set-text-properties 10 20 '(face hi-yellow))
```

When I call

```
(font-lock-mode -1)
```

it works, but all sql highlighting disappears.

There must be a solution because it's possible to select a region and it will be highlighted but I can't figure out how to do it programmatically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightTemporarily.

Both MarkerPens and Highlight provide functions to highlight a region.

Comment: Typo correction: That should be ["HighLight"](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/?action=browse;oldid=HighLight;id=HighlightLibrary), not "Highlight".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

- open ***scratch* buffer and enter:

```
(with-current-buffer "foo" (add-text-properties 1 10 '(comment t face highlight)))
```

- then evaluate with C-j

Characters 1-10 will be highlited in buffer "foo".