# emacs: highlighting balanced expressions (eg. LaTeX tags)

Tags: regex, emacs, latex, elisp, auctex

What would be a good way to get Emacs to highlight an expression that may include things like balanced brackets -- e.g. something like

```
\highlightthis{some \textit{text} here
some more text
done now}
```

`highlight-regex` works nicely for simple things, but I had real trouble writing an emacs regex to recognize line breaks, and of course it matches till the first closing bracket.

(as a secondary question: pointers to any packages that extend emacs regex syntax would be much appreciated -- I am having pretty hard time with it, and I'm fairly familiar with regexes in perl.)

**Edit**: For my specific purpose (LaTeX tags highlighting in an AUCTeX buffer), I was able to get this to work by customizing an AUCTeX specific variable `font-latex-user-keyword-classes`, that adds something like this to `custom-set-variables` in .emacs:

```
'(font-latex-user-keyword-classes (quote (("mycommands" (("highlightthis" "{")) (:slant italic :foreground "red") command))))
```

A more generic solution would still be nice to have though!

Answer (score 1):

You could use functions acting on s-expressions to work with the region you want to highlight, and use one of the solutions mentionned on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/491257/1225607) to actually highlight it.

Here is an example :

```
(defun my/highlight-function ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (search-forward "\highlightthis")
    (let ((end (scan-sexps (point) 1)))
      (add-text-properties (point) end '(comment t face highlight)))))
```

**EDIT :** Here is an example using a similar function with Emacs' standard font locking system, as explained in the [search-based fontification](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html#Search_002dbased-Fontification) section of the emacs-lisp manual :

```
(defun my/highlight-function (bound)
  (if (search-forward "\highlightthis" bound 'noerror)
      (let ((begin  (match-end 0))
            (end    (scan-sexps (point) 1)))
        (set-match-data (list begin end))
        t)
    nil))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(my/highlight-function))))
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I cannot make this work quite yet. First, the solution from the "region highlighting" does not seem to do anything for me -- ie. executing the (add-text-properties 1 10 ... ) statement alone does not highlight symbols 1 through 10. Second, even if I get it to work, I am a bit worried that the highlighting would stay pinned to that place in the buffer. It would be also nice if this could be made to work automatically, like how other syntax highlighting does...

Comment: "I am a bit worried that the highlighting would stay pinned to that place in the buffer" It is not the case : text properties stay attached to their text, not to specific positions in the buffer.

Comment: for you two other concerns, I think the [search-based fontification](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html#Search_002dbased-Fontification) section of the elisp manual should help you. You could in particular add a `function` element to the `font-lock-keywords` variable.

Comment: @laxxy please see my edit for a way to use the highlighting function in Emacs' font locking system. If this solution works, maybe I should remove the first proposition, which is incomplete...