# How to highlight a particular line in emacs?

Tags: emacs, bookmarks

I need to highlight facility for emacs in order to mark some lines in file while working with it.
It should be smth like <kbd>M-s h l</kbd> but should work based on line number, not on a regexp. I want to highlight a current line, but the `hl-line-mode` is not suitable, as I need to highlight many lines, every time I press a specific key on each of them.

Comment: "Some lines" is a region. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491257/emacs-region-highlighting May be you needs `highlight.el` library

Comment: These lines are not sequential. It is just a set of interesting lines.

Comment: Cool, I didn't even know I wanted this.  +1

Comment: The "bm" package from below is what I recommend over reinventing the wheel.  But it is fun to invent a wheel!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I just quickly wrote the following:

```
(defun find-overlays-specifying (prop pos)
  (let ((overlays (overlays-at pos))
        found)
    (while overlays
      (let ((overlay (car overlays)))
        (if (overlay-get overlay prop)
            (setq found (cons overlay found))))
      (setq overlays (cdr overlays)))
    found))

(defun highlight-or-dehighlight-line ()
  (interactive)
  (if (find-overlays-specifying
       'line-highlight-overlay-marker
       (line-beginning-position))
      (remove-overlays (line-beginning-position) (+ 1 (line-end-position)))
    (let ((overlay-highlight (make-overlay
                              (line-beginning-position)
                              (+ 1 (line-end-position)))))
        (overlay-put overlay-highlight 'face '(:background "lightgreen"))
        (overlay-put overlay-highlight 'line-highlight-overlay-marker t))))


(global-set-key [f8] 'highlight-or-dehighlight-line)
```

(Here find-overlays-specifying came from the [manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Finding-Overlays.html#Finding-Overlays))

It will highlight current line, and when used again it will remove it.

Maybe the following could be useful as well: removing all your highlight from the buffer (could be dangerous, you might not want it if you highlight important things)

```
(defun remove-all-highlight ()
  (interactive)
  (remove-overlays (point-min) (point-max))
  )

(global-set-key [f9] 'remove-all-highlight)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the point at the beginning or end of some lines.

Comment: Or, maybe it conflicts with my highlithing of braces.

Comment: but unhighlight still doesnt work of the point at the very end of a line.

Comment: Now that you mention it, it does not work for me to remove it when point is at the end of the line.

Comment: It's good as a temporary solution. But it still has a problem with show-paren-mode, and with hl-line-mode.

Comment: I think I used hl-line-mode but quit it for some reason. What is the complication?

Comment: As it's been said, hl-line-mode uses overlays to highlight current line, and your function detects it as an existing overlay, and doesn't put its own. So line remains highlined only by "Hl" mode, and when i remove point from it, it becomes not marked at all

Comment: If you turn off hl mode, the highlight stays or not?

Comment: And is there a reason you want to use both of these? Otherwise just stick with one or the other :)

Comment: Of corse they both useful, because hl-line-mode helps with messed text with long lines, and highlight-or-degighlight-line helps to accent visually some lines, to mark them.

If I turn off hl mode you highlights are stay. I think you should use some kind of a named overlay, in order to avoid collisions with other modes, but I don't yet know how

Comment: Maybe could you try that part in the edit? Once I figure that part out I can fix this once and for all :)

Comment: I've added the your overlay a uniq property "'line-highlight-overlay-marker" so it will never conflict with other overlay-using mode

Comment: And the answer to the question in the answer:
(#<overlay from 619 to 661 in *scratch*>)

Comment: Feel free to update the answer then. I couldn't pass it another property for some reason...

Comment: if you need to change the color, this is the list http://raebear.net/comp/emacscolors.html

Answer (score 14):

You can use [bm.el](https://github.com/joodland/bm). You can install bm.el from MELPA.

bm.el provides `bm-toggle` to highlight and unhighlight current line.
bm.el also provides `bm-bookmark-regexp` which highlights only matched lines.
And you can jump between highlighted lines by `bm-previous` and `bm-next`

Following is sample configuration of bm.el

```
(require 'bm)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'bm-toggle)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'bm-previous)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 'bm-next)
(global-set-key (kbd "<f8>") 'bm-bookmark-regexp)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's good, but i think a bit heavy for such simple task.

Comment: bm is simple, flexible, powerful and intuitive.

Answer (score 5):

[Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) does what you are asking for. Use [`C-x p RET`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutonamedBookmarks) (by default) to set a bookmark at point. And you can configure the kind of [highlighting](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#DefiningHowtoHighlight) you want for such bookmarks.  This is similar to what `bm.el` offers (syohex's answer), but more flexible.

Comment: Please note that bookmarks won't work in EWW buffers, only in directories and files. I was searching for a solution in Emacs that would allow me to highlight certain lines in an EWW buffer and registers and bookmarks came to my mind. While registers can be used to remember certain points in a webpage buffer and later jump to them, bookmarks can't be used.
(EWW buffers were not a requirement for the OP, I just wanted to extend your answer.)

Comment: @hajovonta: No, I don't think that's true. With Bookmark+, EWW bookmarks should work fine, including for buffers. Of course EWW itself changes all the time, so some change might have introduced a problem I'm not yet aware of. If you feel you've found a problem then please report it to me: `M-x customize-group bookmark-plus`, then follow (e.g. click) the link `Send Bug Report`, which
helps you prepare an email to me. Thx.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I somehow got the feeling that EWW bookmarks are for EWW urls only. I needed to bookmark a position in an EWW buffer. Is that possible with Bookmark+?

Comment: @hajovonta: No, EWW bookmarks work like ordinary bookmarks. They bookmark not just a URL but also the position on that page (e.g. HTML page) where you set the bookmark. And you can also set a region bookmark at such a location.